# Prioritise LiKE query results (sql, mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Let's assume there is a table called 'tbl' with a column called 'name'. I want to do a search for that field, but the scenario should be like this.

- if the search keyword matches in the beginning, those result should come first.
- if the search keyword matches in beginning of second word, those result should come next.
- Like wise (for the third, fourth, fifth, ... words)
- if the search keyword matches in first word (but not in the beginning), those result should come next.
- if the search keyword matches in second word (but not in the beginning, those search result should come next.
- Like wise (for the third, fourth, fifth, ... words)

Simply, I want to order the search results to satisfy the followings.

- Whole word matching is the higher priority.
- Keyword matching priority should go to the first matching word.
- Within the matching word, priority should go to the position of the keyword in that word.

As an example, if the key word is 'city', the results should be come as below order.

City of Ember is my favourite movie
Big city
My city is London
It's a city
The last city on my list was Boston
I live in the city
Capacity the maximum amount that something can contain
Electricity is a mani power source 
My electricity bill is so high
This elevator's capacity is ten people

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  But you can do this as:

```
order by locate(concat(' ', city), concat(' ', column)),
         locate(city, column)
```

The first condition matches the beginning of a word -- assuming that a word starts with a space.  The `locate()` returns the position, so the earlier in the string, the higher the search.

The second condition matches anywhere in the string.  The same condition holds -- earlier in the string is a better match.

Comment: There should be a where clause to filter the data, isn't it? Because there can be more data which doesn't have the word 'city'.

Comment: @asankasri. . . Your question is about ordering.  The `where` clause is pretty simple:  `where column like concat('%', city, '%')`.